# Edit an item in the Listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am making this simple POS application and I would like to edit a item of the listview programatically  if there is one with the same product.

At the bottom of the code there is a condition if it finds it, that works but I am unsure how to edit the list item that is found.

here is my current code

```
            Dim str(5) As String
            Dim itm As ListViewItem
                str(0) = xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText
                str(1) = xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText
                str(2) = "£" + xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText
                str(3) = 1
                str(4) = "£" & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText * str(3) 'works out total (price * quantity)
            itm = New ListViewItem(str)

            Dim findItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.FindItemWithText(xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText)
            If Not findItem Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox("Already in list")
            Else
                ListView1.Items.Add(itm)

            End If
```

Comment: Do you want to edit the item programattically or do you want the user to be able to edit the listbox?

Comment: @DavidWilson programattically

Comment: OK. How do you want to change the found listbox item?

Comment: @DavidWilson I want to edit the text

Comment: Do you mean the text of the subitem that contains the item your're searching for?

Comment: @DavidWilson yeah the subitem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it... I also noticed your using an index as well that is the same as I did `i`; that might conflict and probably will. Just change my `i` to something else if that is the case...

```
  Try
        Dim findItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.FindItemWithText(xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText)
        If findItem IsNot Nothing Then
            For i As Integer = 1 To findItem.SubItems.Count - 1
                If findItem.SubItems(i).Text = xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText Then
                    findItem.SubItems(i).Text = "YourNewTextValue?"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Handle your exception...
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

OK Do you mean something straightforward like this?

```
Dim findItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.FindItemWithText(xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText)
If Not findItem Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("Already in list")
    For Each item As String In findItem.SubItems
        If item = xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText Then
            item = WhateverYourNewDataIs
        End If
    Next
Else
    ListView1.Items.Add(itm)

End If
```

Comment: I get this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from type 'ListViewSubItem' to type 'String' is not valid.

Comment: @anotheruser that's because `findItem.SubItems` is a collection. It actually needs to be looking for the actual type contained in the enumerable collection, hence: `SubItems` and ***not*** `String`. Then you can get the text out of that item and do the compare...

Comment: @Codexer how do I do that

Comment: `ListView1.Items(theindex).SubItems(anotherindex).Text` will get the text out you need.

Comment: @Codexer what should I put in "the index" and "anotherindex"

Comment: @anotheruser please see my answer.